# hdparm -C states the drive is in standby regardless if the drive is in standby or not

Tags: hard-drive, sleep, standby, hdparm

I have a strange issue. I have a WD Green 3TB drive that always reports its in standby. The drive will go to sleep on it's own after 30 minutes (regardless of what I set with hdparm. But if I do -C while its sleeping or while Im actively using it, it always reports "standby".

It is also unresponsive to:

```
sudo hdparm -y /dev/sda
```

Does it not support -C or -y features? If so, is there any other way for me to reduce the standby time from 30min to 15min? And/or be able to check if its in standby or not remotely (ssh) ?

Here is more info about the drive:

```
sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda

/dev/sda:

ATA device, with non-removable media
        Model Number:       WDC WD30EZRX-00D8PB0
        Firmware Revision:  80.00A80
        Transport:          Serial, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
        Supported: 9 8 7 6 5
        Likely used: 9
Configuration:
        Logical         max     current
        cylinders       16383   16383
        heads           16      16
        sectors/track   63      63
        --
        CHS current addressable sectors:    16514064
        LBA    user addressable sectors:   268435455
        LBA48  user addressable sectors:  5860533168
        Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
        Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
        device size with M = 1024*1024:     2861588 MBytes
        device size with M = 1000*1000:     3000592 MBytes (3000 GB)
        cache/buffer size  = unknown
Capabilities:
        LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
        Queue depth: 32
        Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, with device specific minimum
        R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 0
        DMA: *mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 udma6
             Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
        PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4
             Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
        Enabled Supported:
           *    SMART feature set
                Security Mode feature set
           *    Power Management feature set
           *    Write cache
           *    Look-ahead
           *    Host Protected Area feature set
           *    WRITE_BUFFER command
           *    READ_BUFFER command
           *    NOP cmd
           *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
                Power-Up In Standby feature set
           *    SET_FEATURES required to spinup after power up
                SET_MAX security extension
           *    48-bit Address feature set
           *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
           *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
           *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
           *    SMART error logging
           *    SMART self-test
           *    General Purpose Logging feature set
           *    64-bit World wide name
           *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
           *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
           *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
           *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
           *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
           *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
           *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
           *    Host-initiated interface power management
           *    Phy event counters
           *    NCQ priority information
           *    READ_LOG_DMA_EXT equivalent to READ_LOG_EXT
                DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
                Device-initiated interface power management
           *    Software settings preservation
           *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
           *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
           *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
           *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
                unknown 206[12] (vendor specific)
                unknown 206[13] (vendor specific)
                unknown 206[14] (vendor specific)
Security:
        Master password revision code = 65534
                supported
        not     enabled
        not     locked
        not     frozen
        not     expired: security count
                supported: enhanced erase
        430min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 430min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 50014ee058f13d3c
        NAA             : 5
        IEEE OUI        : 0014ee
        Unique ID       : 058f13d3c
Checksum: correct
```

It does spit at me an error when I try to use -C or -y, but I am not sure what this long hex string means. And from what I understand it has to be able to read the drive to get that "drive state is: standby", otherwise it wouldnt print that?

```
sudo hdparm -C /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 drive state is:  standby

sudo hdparm -y /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 issuing standby command
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a WD-issue. I have a WD8003FRYZ and hdparm -C also always yields ›standby‹, although the drive is spinning.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).